# SSRS "like" operator with nested iif

Tags: reporting-services

I have been trying to get a nested iif to work with the "like" operator and cannot come up with the right syntax. The basic code is shown below and before it is suggested, I have also tried this with the SWITCH operator with similar errors. The expression editor moves the error around based on the parenthesis. This particular expression is in the "fill" property of a matrix in an SSRS report. I really want to set the color on a match and leave it unchanged for no match. For the code below the expression editor shows an error on the first comma after the text "*Preferred*".

```
=iif((Fields!PHASE_TYPE.Value like "*Preferred*","ForestGreen","Blue") or
(Fields!PHASE_TYPE.Value like "*Maintain*","DarkSeaGreen","Red"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not quite right for a `IIF` function. It takes 3 parameters, and you are only really giving it one.

You are going to need to change your expression to some like the one below.

```
=Switch(Fields!PHASE_TYPE.Value like "*Preferred*","ForestGreen",
    Fields!PHASE_TYPE.Value like "*Maintain*","DarkSeaGreen",
    True, "White") ' This last part will catch anything that does not match the above
```